# Python's Pandas module not finding file in same directory

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and the pandas library, and I'm facing this issue: Python's pandas library is not finding the file I'm trying to open, even though is in the same directory as the script.
Until yesterday, I was using pandas and using the same lines of code, and it was working perfectly, so I'm very confused. I can run the script fine from a CMD window, but not from Jupyter Lab nor from VSCode.
This is my code:

```
from pandas import *

london = read_csv('London_2014.csv')
print(london.head())
```

And this is the list of errors I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Lautte\Desktop\PY\OPEN UNIVERSITY\Learn-to-code-for-data-analysis-master\2_Cleaning_up_our_act\test2.py", line 
3, in <module>
    london = read_csv('London_2014.csv')
  File "C:\Users\Lautte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lautte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 680, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Lautte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 575, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Lautte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 933, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\Lautte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1217, in _make_engine       
    self.handles = get_handle(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
  File "C:\Users\Lautte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 789, in get_handle
    handle = open(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'London_2014.csv'
```

Thank you in advance, and have a nice week!

Comment: Hey, couple of beginner tips. Don't do star imports, they're considered bad practice just do pd.WhatYouWant i.e. pd.read_csv. Second, it works in CMD because the working directory is the same as the script, but not from vscode because you probably didn't change the directory of the terminal to be the folder where you have your script and the csv file. You could use absolute path like: london = read_csv("""c:\Users\Lautte\Desktop\PY\OPEN UNIVERSITY\Learn-to-code-for-data-analysis-master\2_Cleaning_up_our_act\London_2014.csv""") should work anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of beginner tips. Don't do star imports, they're considered bad practice just do pd.WhatYouWant i.e. pd.read_csv. Second, it works in CMD because the working directory is the same as the script, but not from vscode because you probably didn't properly change the directory of the terminal to be the folder where you have your script and the csv file. You could use absolute path instead of the relative like: london = read_csv("""c:\Users\Lautte\Desktop\PY\OPEN UNIVERSITY\Learn-to-code-for-data-analysis-master\2_Cleaning_up_our_act\London_2014.csv""") which should work anywhere.

Comment: Thank you! It has already been solved by resetting my cpu twice (?) I don't know why it happened, or why resetting was needed, but VSCode and Jupyter now run everything smoothly. 
Also: I'm picking up on the * import tip, thank your for that one as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the `London_2014.csv` in the directory?

You can also try:

```
import pandas as pd

london = pd.read_csv('./London_2014.csv')
print(london.head())
```

or pass the absolute file path to the file `London_2014.csv` to `pd.read_csv`

Answer (score -1):

You can re-write your code like this

```
import pandas as pd

london = pd.read_csv('London_2014.csv')
print(london.head())
```

and don't use `from pandas import *`